# Get rid of vertex labels in graph plot in R

Tags: r, plot, igraph

I am working on a small project that involves finding community structure of the graph and plotting. I am using label.propagation.community algorithm for community detection and following line of code for plotting:

```
plot(community_1, graph_1)
```

It is working as expected, giving the following plot.[image].

The problem is that the graph it is showing the vertex labels that make the plot look more congested. Is there any way I can get rid of these labels from the plot? I do not want to modify anything in the graph and community; just want to tell the plot to not print the labels.

Comment: Like this: `plot(community_1, graph_1, vertex.label=NA)`?

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 19):

For those like me who stumbled across this while knee deep in the attributes of igraph plots, the full list of `graph` attributes available in `igraph` plots is available here: http://kateto.net/networks-r-igraph

In section 5.1 you will find:

> 5.1 Plotting parameters
>
> NODES
>
> vertex.color   Node color
>
> vertex.frame.color     Node border color
>
> vertex.shape   One of “none”, “circle”, “square”, “csquare”,
>   “rectangle”
>
> “crectangle”, “vrectangle”, “pie”, “raster”, or “sphere” vertex.size
>      Size of the node (default is 15) vertex.size2   The second size of
>   the node (e.g. for a rectangle)
>
> vertex.label   Character vector used to label the nodes
>
> vertex.label.family    Font family of the label (e.g.“Times”,
>   “Helvetica”)
>
> vertex.label.font      Font: 1 plain, 2 bold, 3, italic, 4 bold italic, 5
>   symbol
>
> vertex.label.cex   Font size (multiplication factor, device-dependent)
>
> vertex.label.dist      Distance between the label and the vertex
>
> vertex.label.degree    The position of the label in relation to the 
>   vertex,  where 0 right, “pi” is left, “pi/2” is below, and “-pi/2” is
>   above
>
> EDGES
>
> edge.color     Edge color
>
> edge.width     Edge width, defaults to 1
>
> edge.arrow.size    Arrow size, defaults to 1
>
> edge.arrow.width   Arrow width, defaults to 1
>
> edge.lty   Line type, could be 0 or “blank”, 1 or “solid”, 2 or
>   “dashed”,  3 or “dotted”, 4 or “dotdash”, 5 or “longdash”, 6 or
>   “twodash”
>
> edge.label     Character vector used to label edges
>
> edge.label.family      Font family of the label (e.g.“Times”,
>   “Helvetica”)
>
> edge.label.font    Font: 1 plain, 2 bold, 3, italic, 4 bold italic, 5
>   symbol
>
> edge.label.cex     Font size for edge labels
>
> edge.curved    Edge curvature, range 0-1 (FALSE sets it to 0, TRUE to
>   0.5)
>
> arrow.mode     Vector specifying whether edges should have arrows, 
>   possible values: 0 no arrow, 1 back, 2 forward, 3 both
>
> OTHER
>
> margin     Empty space margins around the plot, vector with length 4
>
> frame      if TRUE, the plot will be framed
>
> main   If set, adds a title to the plot
>
> sub    If set, adds a subtitle to the plot

From this, and as helpfully pointed out by @VincentGuillemot you can use the `vertex.label` parameter to manipulate node labels.

To remove labels, you can write:

```
plot(community_1, graph_1, vertex.label=NA)
```